# Ignore Avro schema for an specific field that contains a multi-level nested json

Tags: json, avro, confluent-platform

We have been using **Avro** specific type to manage schema evolution for our application. The issue we have been facing is due to the unknown schema for a field (might be a json object with multiple levels), we need to somehow disable the entire schema validation for whatever comes for a single field (only a single field). I was wondering how this is possible.

Some solutions have come out to our minds, but none of them is ideal.

- Use string data type for that field and make it a single line json object. However, with this approach, we will be losing the readability of the field specially during a debug.
- Use map type for that field (however, since we don't know how many levels we have and what type of field value we are going to have, I am not sure if this actually works)
- Use byte type for this field and serialize and deserialize it separately (probably the worst option)

I am not sure if there is any way that we can disable schema for a specific field in Avro. I would appreciate if someone can help me with this matter.